# How to set GenericPrincipal of threads created automatically C#

Tags: c#, role-base-authorization, genericprincipal

I have the code in application like

```
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(currentIdentity, roles);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

but problem is when my application runs some threads are created automatically but there principle is not same as above one. How to set that?

Comment: Setting Thread.CurrentPrincipal propagates the principal to all child threads during the time of creation. Are these other threads not created by the thread which sets the principal?

Comment: actually I am using MEF and Prism. I dont have control over threads creation.